# How do I use SOAP service in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I am new to SOAP in php. SOAP is enabled in my Apache. I have a sample code. The code contains the line `require_once('SOAP/Client.php');`. When running the file I am getting the fatal error like `Warning: require_once(SOAP/Client.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream:`. Do I need to place the SOAP package inside my example file folder. If yes there also am getting some errors. How do I handle this. Please advise.

Below is my code,

```
`<?php

// bind SOAP/Client.php -> path of the php file
require_once "SOAP/Client.php";

// URI delivered to web service
$sc = new SOAP_Client("http://domain/SOAP/Server.php");

// start call function to use the function of the Web Service
$parameter = array();
$result = $sc->call ("now", &$parameter, "urn:TimeSerivce");

// print result
print $result."\n";

?>`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more information -- what soap "package" are you trying to use? Sample code? Does the "package" not have documentation of its own?

Comment: Below is my sample code.<?php

// bind SOAP/Client.php -> path of the php file
require_once "SOAP/Client.php";

// URI delivered to web service
$sc = new SOAP_Client("http://localhost/SOAP/Server.php");

// start call function to use the function of the Web Service
$parameter = array();
$result = $sc->call ("now", &$parameter, "urn:TimeSerivce");

// print result
print $result."\n";

?>

Comment: You can edit your question to include that sample code, that way you can format it. Also, that isn't all that is needed. What do you expect `SOAP/Server.php` to be? Is it a file you downloaded? Where did you get it? What is it? Does it have documentation? We can't possibly diagnose problems with unknown and unspecified code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using the library SoapClient is possible (SoapClient must be enabled, see phpinfo).
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

If the server you are trying to connect require CA cert, ai belive the only way is using cURL.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Cheers!